# How the convert the code below form C#2008 to C#2005 have got Dictionary?

Tags: c#-2.0

I want convert the code below form C#2008 to C#2005 have got Dictionary

```cs
Dictionary<GridCell, CellColors> cellColorsCahe = new Dictionary<GridCell, CellColors>();
void gridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
    {
    foreach (var item in cellColorsCahe)
        {
        if (item.Key.RowHandle == e.RowHandle && item.Key.Column == e.Column)
            {
            e.Appearance.ForeColor = item.Value.ForeColor;
            e.Appearance.BackColor = item.Value.BackColor;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And? [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.80).aspx) existed back in C# 2 (the version of the C# language that is the default used by Visual Studio 2005, which is what I presume you mean by C#2005). Are you getting compiler errors? If so, what? Are you getting runtime errors? If so, what? Are you getting unexpected behaviour? If so, what?

Comment: line error message below when I run on C# 2.0 foreach (var item in cellColorsCahe) and instead var = Dictionary<GridCell, CellColors> will error: //Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.GridCell,ColorCellCondition.CellColors>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.GridCell,ColorCellCondition.CellColors>'
foreach (Dictionary<GridCell, CellColors> item in cellColorsCahe)

Comment: Pretty unlikely you should be doing that, just change the project's Framework target to 2.0.  If you need to do this because somebody is using a 10 year old version of Visual Studio then I'd recommend you make it his problem :)  Only way to inspire him to update.

Answer (score 0):

So, it would seem the problem you're having is not, specifically, about [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.80).aspx) but instead with the use of [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) which is not supported in C#2.

In this case, you need to supply the correct data type. Unfortunately, from your comment, you've attempted the wrong one. When you enumerate a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, the iteration variable is *not* a dictionary, but is instead a [`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.80).aspx). So you'd want:

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<GridCell, CellColors> item in cellColorsCahe)
```

instead.